# Access Target Drop element in React dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

Using React Dnd v15.1.1

I need to get the **target element on drop** either their Id or the whole object

I tried

```
const [{ canDrop, isOver }, drop] = useDrop(
  () => ({
     accept: ItemType,
     drop: (item, monitor) => addTaskToSprint(item.id, monitor),
  })
);
```

And here's addTaskToSprint declaration

```
const addTaskToSprint = (id, monitor) => {
    console.log(monitor.getDropResult());

    let body = {
       sprint: { 
          id: , //here where I need the target Drop Id 
       }
    };
    axios.put(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/tasks/" + id, body, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}` },
    });
};
```

monitor.getDropResult() is returning null in the console

Then I tried the same process inside the drag declaration

```
const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
    type: ItemType,
    item: task,
    collect: (monitor) => ({ isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging() }),
    end(item, monitor) {
        console.log(monitor.getDropResult());
    },
}));
```

And in here it's returning the dropEffect. Here's the logs

```
{
   "dropEffect": "move"
}
```

When I console.log(monitor) inside the drop result it gave me

[image: console results to logging monitor object]

Where **targetId** is the targeted drop element, but this Id is generated by react-dnd not the actual Id of the element

When I open the internalMonitor object from the picture above

I got inside nested objects all the drop Targets with their generated Id from react-dnd but I couldn't get the object of each Id (to get the target drop object)

[image: console result of internalMonitor object]

And here's how each object looks like

```
0: {"T0" => DropTargetImpl}
    key: "T0"
    value: DropTargetImpl
        monitor: DropTargetMonitorImpl
        internalMonitor: DragDropMonitorImpl
        registry: HandlerRegistryImpl {types: Map(8), dragSources: Map(4), dropTargets: Map(4), pinnedSourceId: null, pinnedSource: null, …}
        store: {dispatch: ƒ, subscribe: ƒ, getState: ƒ, replaceReducer: ƒ, @@observable: ƒ}
    spec:
      accept: "Task Card"
      collect: monitor => {…}
      drop: (item, monitor) => addTaskToSprint(item.id, monitor, drop)
```

To be clearer, check the screenshot of the results in the console

[image]

Comment: looking forward ...

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same challenge trying to use the monitor object of react dnd library, but was getting the same result as yours. I decided to share here how I've solved that. The solution is pretty simple and you can pass whatever info you need to the props collection when rendering the draggable / droppable component and then you use that info within the useDrag() / useDrop() methods.

Here below is an example of how to control draggable answers, so that to be dropped on a form depending on the exercise / task they belong to (item.task_id === props.task_id):

```
function DnDAnswerTarget(props) {
const [{canDrop, isOver}, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: // ItemTypes to be specified,
    canDrop: (item, monitor) => {
        return (item.task_id === props.task_id ? true : false);
    },
    drop: (item, monitor) => {
       // Some code for the ondrop event to be executed...
    },
    collect: (monitor) => (
        {
        canDrop: !!monitor.canDrop(),
        isOver: !!monitor.isOver()
    })
});
return (
    <Box ref={drop}
    >
        {props.children}
    </Box>
  );
}
export default DnDAnswerTarget;
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem here is that `monitor.getDropResult()` gives you [the value returned by your `drop()` function](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drop), but if you're calling `addTaskToSprint()` directly from `drop()` then the drop result isn't available yet.

You have a couple of choices here.

If you want to call `addTaskToSprint()` from the drop target, you might add an extra parameter to accept the target id directly:

```
drop: (task) => addTaskToSprint(task.id, sprint.id)
```

Alternatively, if you want to call `addTaskToSprint` from the dragged object, you could return the target element id from the `drop()` function and [it will be available to the `end` handler](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drag):

```
// in useDrop() ...
drop: () => ({ sprintId: sprint.id })

// in useDrag() ...
end(task, monitor) {
    const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult();
    addTaskToSprint(task.id, dropResult.sprintId);
}
```